all_bluetooth package with lateinit error
The code is copied from: https://pub.dev/packages/all_bluetooth/example. My projects pubspec.ymal  (only depenedecies part)
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  plugin_platform_interface: ^2.0.2
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  all_bluetooth: ^0.1.0

And the AndroidManifest.xml:
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
    <!-- The INTERNET permission is required for development. Specifically,
         the Flutter tool needs it to communicate with the running application
         to allow setting breakpoints, to provide hot reload, etc.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
</manifest>

I can make the connection to a RN52 BT-module from Microchip and the code goes to the ChatScreen class as expected. But if I send something I get the error:
E/flutter (20020): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, lateinit property sendReceive has not been initialized, null, kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property sendReceive has not been initialized

I made one month ago a treat already here: flutte all_bluetooth example code PlatformException error lateinit property sendReceive has not been initialized but nobody replied.
import 'package:all_bluetooth/all_bluetooth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
// import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

void main() async {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

// void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

final _allBluetooth = AllBluetooth();

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: StreamBuilder<ConnectionResult>(
          stream: _allBluetooth.listenForConnection,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            final state = snapshot.data?.state ?? false;
            if (state == true) {
              final device = snapshot.data!.device;
              debugPrint('$device');
              return ChatScreen(device: device!);
            }
            return const HomeScreen();
          },
        ),
      );
}

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  bool listeningForClient = false;

  final bondedDevices = ValueNotifier<List<BluetoothDevice>>([]);
  final scannedDevices = ValueNotifier<List<BluetoothDevice>>([]);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    const MethodChannel("method_channel").invokeMethod("permit");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<bool>(
      stream: _allBluetooth.streamBluetoothState,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        final bluetoothOn = snapshot.data ?? false;
        return Scaffold(
          floatingActionButton: switch (listeningForClient) {
            true => null,
            false => FloatingActionButton(
                backgroundColor: switch (bluetoothOn) {
                  true => Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                  false => Colors.red,
                },
                onPressed: switch (bluetoothOn) {
                  false => null,
                  true => () {
                      _allBluetooth.startBluetoothServer();
                      setState(() {
                        listeningForClient = true;
                      });
                    },
                },
                child: const Icon(Icons.wifi_tethering),
              )
          },
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text("Bluetooth Connect"),
          ),
          body: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: switch (listeningForClient) {
              true => Center(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      const Text("Waiting"),
                      const CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      FloatingActionButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            listeningForClient = false;
                          });
                          _allBluetooth.closeConnection();
                        },
                        child: const Icon(Icons.stop),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              false => Column(
                  children: [
                    SingleChildScrollView(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            switch (bluetoothOn) {
                              true => "ON  ",
                              false => "OFF  ",
                            },
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: bluetoothOn ? Colors.green : Colors.red,
                            ),
                          ),
                          ElevatedButton(
                            onPressed: switch (bluetoothOn) {
                              false => null,
                              true => () {
                                  _allBluetooth
                                      .getBondedDevices()
                                      .then((newDevices) {
                                    bondedDevices.value = newDevices;
                                  });
                                },
                            },
                            child: const Text("Bond.Dev."),
                          ),
                          ElevatedButton(
                            onPressed: switch (bluetoothOn) {
                              false => null,
                              true => () {
                                  _allBluetooth.startDiscovery();
                                },
                            },
                            child: const Text("Disc."),
                          ),
                          ElevatedButton(
                            onPressed: switch (bluetoothOn) {
                              false => null,
                              true => () {
                                  _allBluetooth.stopDiscovery();
                                  _allBluetooth.discoverDevices.listen((event) {
                                    scannedDevices.value = [
                                      ...scannedDevices.value,
                                      event
                                    ];
                                  });
                                },
                            },
                            child: const Text("Stop disc."),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    if (!bluetoothOn)
                      const Center(child: Text("Turn bluetooth on"))
                    else
                      Expanded(
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              DeviceListWidget(
                                notifier: bondedDevices,
                                title: "Paired Devices",
                              ),
                              DeviceListWidget(
                                notifier: scannedDevices,
                                title: "Scanned Devices",
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                  ],
                ),
            },
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class ChatScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final BluetoothDevice device;

  const ChatScreen({super.key, required this.device});

  @override
  State<ChatScreen> createState() => _ChatScreenState();
}

class _ChatScreenState extends State<ChatScreen> {
  final messageListener = ValueNotifier(<String>[]);
  final messageController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _allBluetooth.listenForData.listen((event) {
      if (event != null) {
        messageListener.value = [
          ...messageListener.value,
          event,
        ];
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    messageController.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.device.name),
        actions: [
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: _allBluetooth.closeConnection,
            child: const Text("CLOSE"),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: ValueListenableBuilder(
                  valueListenable: messageListener,
                  builder: (context, messages, child) {
                    return ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: messages.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        final msg = messages[index];
                        return Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
                          child: DecoratedBox(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                            ),
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                              child: Text(
                                msg,
                                style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.green),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    );
                  }),
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: TextField(
                    controller: messageController,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
                  child: FloatingActionButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      final message = messageController.text;
                      _allBluetooth.sendMessage(message);
                      messageController.clear();
                      FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
                    },
                    child: const Icon(Icons.send),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DeviceListWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final ValueNotifier<List<BluetoothDevice>> notifier;

  const DeviceListWidget({
    required this.notifier,
    required this.title,
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: ValueListenableBuilder(
          valueListenable: notifier,
          builder: (context, value, child) {
            return Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      title,
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 16,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(value.length.toString()),
                  ],
                ),
                Flexible(
                  fit: FlexFit.loose,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                    itemCount: value.length,
                    itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
                      final device = value[index];
                      return ListTile(
                        title: Text(device.name),
                        subtitle: Text(device.address),
                        onTap: () async {
                          _allBluetooth.connectToDevice(device.address);
                        },
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}


This will be a problem in the package itself, so you either fork the package and fix it or you create an issue and wait. If you use classic bluetooth, you can try out https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bluetooth_serial as an alternative, which worked for my projects.
